Is there a way to deduce a type from an object?
I have the following object:
const rights = [{
  label: 'Dashboard',
  value: 'dashboard',
  children: [
    {
      label: 'Statistics',
      value: 'stats',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Read',
          value: 'read',
        },
        {
          label: 'Write',
          value: 'write',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'CSV Export',
      value: 'csvExport',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'Read',
          value: 'read',
        },
        {
          label: 'Write',
          value: 'write',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}] as const;

From this object, I want to derive the following type:
{
  dashboard: {
    statistics: {
      read: boolean,
      write: boolean,
    },
    csvExport: {
      read: boolean,
      write: boolean,
    },
  }
}

However, it seems that recursion in TypeScript is limited. I have tried many different approaches but cannot figure out how to achieve this.
How can I recursively generate a type from this nested structure?
Edit : it is the best I've got but I'm still far from what I want :

type ObjectType = typeof object;

type CurrentNode = {
  readonly label: string;
  readonly value: string;
  readonly children?: CurrentNode[];
};

type TransformToBoolean2<T extends CurrentNode[]> = {
  [K in T[number]['value']]: T[number]['children'] extends CurrentNode[]
    ? TransformToBoolean2<T[number]['children']>
    : boolean;
};

type booleanObject = TransformToBoolean2<ObjectType>;


The type of booleanObject is the following :
type booleanObject = {
    a: boolean;
} 

And more than this, my linter informs me that ObjectType doesn't satisfy 'CurrentNode[]'

However, it seems that recursion in TypeScript is limited. In what way was it that does not meet your requirements? I have tried many different approaches but cannot figure out how to achieve this. Can you show a few that were the best you've got and explain where you got stuck?

What's the logic?

T['children'] extends CurrentNode does not hold, as T['children'] is the array CurrentNode[]. TransformToBoolean2<T['children']> would fail for the same reason.

I edited again, I renamed the values to make it more understandable and applied your suggestions

I think you'll need a proper mapped type instead of K in T[number]['value']. Otherwise T[number]['children'] will not produce anything useful.

Thank you @Bergi but I'm not sure to understand your reply. If you mean that I should content myself with a mapped type like [key: string]: boolean, I unfortunately cannot because I need a strict object to make an autocomplete feature in the future. Don't hesitate to tell me if I wasn't clear.

No, I mean a mapped type (see the link), not just an index signature.

I checked the link but I don't really know what do you mean by using a proper mapped type then.
